# How to refresh visible data when it becomes outdated on Android?

Tags: android, timer, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

In an activity I'm showing some data. I calculate the data in a `ViewModel` and store it in a `LiveData`.

Now the problem is that the data refers to the current day, so at midnight it becomes outdated and needs to be recalculated if it is still currently displayed.

Should I do this in the `Activity` or in the `ViewModel` and what kind of timer should I use for this?

Comment: Sounds like you should use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) to schedule the task.

Comment: @Tonnie Unless I'm missing something I cannot schedule the work at a specific time with WorkManager? It seems I can only set a delay, but I can do that with a Handler as well and much simpler.

Comment: yeah you are right that WorkManager is not exact and is for Deferrable work - any task which is still useful even if it is not run immediately. Your case is that preciseness so WM is out. Please also checkout [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)